# How to use custom models in Django?

Tags: python, django

Followed the Django Quickstart tutorial [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/) and it all worked wo/ problems.

Now when I added a custom APIView I started having trouble. Namely the custom models I created.

Here is my views.py

```
class ValuationDetails(APIView):

   def get(self, request, format=None):
       serializer = ValuationRequestSerializer(data=request.data)
       if serializer.is_valid():
           return Response('Valuation report', status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Here is my ValuationRequestSerializer:

```
class ValuationRequestSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ValuationRequest
        fields = ('street', 'number', 'latitude', 'longitude')
```

Here is my ValuationRequest:

```
from django.db import models

class ValuationRequest(models.Model):
    def __init__(self, street, number, latitude, longitude):
        self.street = street
        self.number = number
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.longitude = longitude
```

The first exception was:

> RuntimeError: Model class valuationservice.valproperty.model.val_models.ValuationRequest doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.

Then I added in the setting.py INSTALLED_APPS a line

```
'valuationservice.valproperty.model.val_models'
```

The second exception after that was:

> django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.

I guess there are two questions:

1. How can I use custom models in Django?
2. What is missing that the Django doesn't like by throwing the first exception?

Python version 2.7.12

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should not define an `__init__` method in your model class.

(If you did, you should always be sure to call the superclass method using `super()`; but you shouldn't do it at all in this case.)

Comment: This is like so in any tutorial I look at. How should the constructor be defined then?

Comment: No it isn't; point to where it's shown like that in any Django tutorial. Quite simply you don't need a "constructor" for a Django model. Model fields are declared at class level, using model Field subclasses as attributes.

Comment: See the "Hand" example. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-model-fields/
Then I am lost, where do I define the model properties then, in the serializable?

Comment: I don't understand the relevance of that link. You're not creating a custom field.

Comment: Please do the actual Django tutorial, especially part 2 at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial02/ - this tells you how to define models.